# Removing "dead" user accounts from TFS & SQL after server migration

Tags: sql, tfs, migration

I have searched high and low for a solution to this problem to no avail.

Basically, the situation is as follows:

We are currently migrating our existing TFS server to another machine, which has been going well up until now.
Unfortunately i'm unable to complete the configuration of Report server and the likes as I get the following error:

**"Failed to add SWSERVER\susan account to the TFSEXECROLE role on the Tfs_Warehouse relational database"**

SWSERVER is the name of the previous machine that hosted the TFS server.

The thing is that SWSERVER\susan is an absolete account, and was actually removed as a user account on the previous machine, which I think is a major part of the problem.

From what I can gather is that TFS can still see it in the restored databases and thinks it's a viable account but seeing as the account technically doesn't exist it can't actually do anything with it.

Another part of the question is that if I go to the original (SWSERVER) and remove the SWSERVER\susan user, will that have an effect on how TFS or SQL operate especially if that account (or any other similar account) are linked to anything in either program?

I'd much appreciate any help anyone can provide.
I've hope i've explained my situation well enough but if anybody needs any more information, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: Are these servers joined to a domain or stand alone?

Comment: Currently they're standalone, there's a domain controller on the network but it doesn't seem to have been used in any significant way.

I've inherited a bit of a mess and i'm still working things out.

Will a domain be involved have an effect on it?

Comment: You need to look at 'changing environment' in the TFS documentation. It will be documented for Domain->Domain but what you really have with a non-domain joined server is a local domain of the same name as the server... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to thank you for your reply and help. As it turns out I was flogging a dead horse with the TFS Reporting setups when I found out that the reports aren't even used currently on the existing setup.

I did however manage to figure out that if I added every user that previously existed as Windows users on the new machine and then used the **TFSconfig Identities /change** command to change the domain (machine name, in this case) name to that of the new server then I stopped getting the error messages and after 3-4 reinstall attempts all seems to be working the way it should.

This link was incredibly helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can't remove users, they will fall out of scope anyway, however that is not your problem. Your TFS instance has been moved from one server to another without following the documented procedure.

You need to follow the instruction to [Move Team Foundation Server from one environment to another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx). Although they will be based on the more common move of Domain to Domain you can think of a non-domain joined server as having a domain of the same name as the local computer.

Now this documentation also follow as using the same hardware so you will need to mix and match between [Move Team Foundation Server from one environment to another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx) and Move [Team Foundation Server from one hardware configuration to another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx).

While not really that hard you do need to follow all of the steps...